# Why does max-width behave counter intuitively on columns in a table?

Tags: html, cross-browser, css

Basically, I have a stretchy table, I want my label column to be fixed width and my data column to be dynamically sized. My inclination would be to set the `max-width` via CSS on my label column. However, this has ***the opposite*** effect. [I've created a jsfiddle that replicates this.](http://jsfiddle.net/gTbpZ/) (Re-size the window to see the left column dynamically sized and the right column fixed size)

On my own site, I see the same behavior and it happens in IE and Chrome.

[If I switch it, and set `max-width` on the data column](http://jsfiddle.net/5ZNSA/1/), everything behaves as I want, but it feels backwards to me. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Why not apply a class or ID to your `<th>` tag and simply set a `width`

Comment: @Anagio, I am using this for a detail view of my data. In this case, I am not using a `<th>` tag on the table.

Comment: Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/GyEGq/ you can wrap your label text within a div and apply the width to that div which will stay fixed

Comment: That's a quick example would need to be cleaned up with more styles

Comment: @Anagio That doesn't seem to do what I want, checkout my second fiddle which does what I want, but with max-width assigned to what seems to me the wrong class: http://jsfiddle.net/5ZNSA/1/

Comment: Using chrome developer tool removing max-width from your data column doesn't affect it. It's not needed in that column for that class. Because the table is 100% width and now only your label column has the `width` set which is holding it's size. So I guess its working?

Comment: Forked without max-width http://jsfiddle.net/5JGrF/

Comment: @Anagio That JS fiddle works as I would expect. I will try on my full site and report back.

Comment: @Anagio post your suggestion as an answer and I can accept it. Removing the width completely from the data column behaves correctly.

Comment: thanks I posted the comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using chrome developer tool removing max-width from your data column doesn't affect it. It's not needed in that column for that class. Because the table is 100% width and now only your label column has the width set which is holding it's size. So I guess its working?

Answer (score 1):

Setting widths on tables has always been a bit... odd. "width" is actually taken to mean "min-width" most of the time, because originally "min-width" didn't exist.

But now, you can force the table to behave itself by adding `table-layout:fixed` to its CSS.

Now you have another problem: This table layout takes the widths of the cells in the first row, and uses them for the whole table.

So, you can add a `<colgroup>` to the table, before the first row. This allows you to set a limited number of styles, but most importantly `width`. I have never tried using `max-width`, but I imagine it may well work. You may be safer with a percentage width, though.